# Изменение значения поля в конкретном div с помощью JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Делаю магазин на вордпрес, в магазине есть на главной 12 товаров, все товары имеют одинаковый div, вот html блока товара

```
                        <div class="col-4 left">
                        <div class="imgGoods"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/tovar.jpg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="titleGoods">Огурец с языком</div>
                        <div class="descGoods">Маринованное мясо на кости, цельный картофель. Отдельно подается резанный репчатый лук</div>
                        <div class="infoGoods">
                            <div class="price left">
                                <span class="priceNum">1920</span>
                                <span class="curencyNum">тенге</span>
                            </div>
                            <form action="" class="left formNum">
                                <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum downNum"></a>
                                <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="numGoods left">
                                <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum upNum"></a>
                            </form>
                            <a href="#" class="right transition inCart">В корзину</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Вот картинка как все выглядит [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, есть div с классом `col-4`, который просто повторяется, в этом div есть поле для количества, слева и справа - минус и плюс, соответственно при клике на плюсик количество +1, при клике на минус количество -1, вроде пока все понятно объяснил. Прописал даже скрипт

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".downNum").click(function() {
      var num = $('.numGoods').val();
      var num = parseInt(num);
      var num = num - 1;
      if (num > 1) {
        $('.numGoods').val(num);
      }
      else {
        $('.numGoods').val('1');
      }
    }); 
    $( ".upNum" ).click(function() {
      var num = $('.numGoods').val();
      var num = parseInt(num);
      var num = num + 1;
      $('.numGoods').val(num);
    });  
});
```

Все работает, **но есть одно но**, оно изменяет количество во всех div, а мне нужно, чтобы изменялось только в этом div, в котором идет click.

Comment: рискну предположить, что товары выводятся циклом. генерируйте в нем id для дива и меняйте кол-во для элемента с нужным id. в id передавайте например порядковый номер товара на странице. совершенно неясно зачем использовать тэг формы.

Comment: Эх.. задубликатить бы... `$(this).closest`

Comment: @Qwertiy, а зачем там клозест?

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы подняться до блока с продуктом

Comment: да можно бьло выводить скрытно ID или вставить в какой-нибудь атрибут, но это гемор, плюс оно и индексироватся может.

Comment: @Grundy, см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменялось только в одном - не стоит выбирать *все*.

Данный селектор `$('.numGoods')` выбирает все элементы с данным классом.

Стоит воспользоваться функциями [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) и [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) в зависимости от кнопки которую нажали

```
$( ".downNum").click(function() {
  var numGoods = $(this).next();
  var num = parseInt(numGoods.val()) - 1;
  if (num > 1) {
    numGoods.val(num);
  }
  else {
    numGoods.val('1');
  }
}); 
$( ".upNum" ).click(function() {
  var numGoods = $(this).prev();
  var num = parseInt(numGoods.val())+1;
  numGoods.val(num);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, идеально все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Разметку почти не трогал, только добавил класс `item`.

```js
$(function () {
  $("body").on('click', ".downNum, .upNum", function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    var $input = $target.closest(".item").find(".numGoods");
    $input.val(Math.max(1, +$input.val() + ($target.hasClass("downNum") ? -1 : 1)));
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-4 left item">
  <div class="imgGoods"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/tovar.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="titleGoods">Огурец с языком</div>
  <div class="descGoods">Маринованное мясо на кости, цельный картофель. Отдельно подается резанный репчатый лук</div>
  <div class="infoGoods">
    <div class="price left">
      <span class="priceNum">1920</span>
      <span class="curencyNum">тенге</span>
    </div>
    <form action="" class="left formNum">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum downNum">-</a>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="numGoods left">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum upNum">+</a>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="right transition inCart">В корзину</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-4 left item">
  <div class="imgGoods"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/tovar.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="titleGoods">Огурец с языком</div>
  <div class="descGoods">Маринованное мясо на кости, цельный картофель. Отдельно подается резанный репчатый лук</div>
  <div class="infoGoods">
    <div class="price left">
      <span class="priceNum">1920</span>
      <span class="curencyNum">тенге</span>
    </div>
    <form action="" class="left formNum">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum downNum">-</a>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="numGoods left">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum upNum">+</a>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="right transition inCart">В корзину</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-4 left item">
  <div class="imgGoods"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/tovar.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="titleGoods">Огурец с языком</div>
  <div class="descGoods">Маринованное мясо на кости, цельный картофель. Отдельно подается резанный репчатый лук</div>
  <div class="infoGoods">
    <div class="price left">
      <span class="priceNum">1920</span>
      <span class="curencyNum">тенге</span>
    </div>
    <form action="" class="left formNum">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum downNum">-</a>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="numGoods left">
      <a href="javascrip:void(0);" class="left UpDownNum upNum">+</a>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="right transition inCart">В корзину</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вместо item мог существующий formNum использовать :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, можно.