# Проблема с селекторами

Tags: jquery, html5

У нас есть n-блоков !В каждом есть селекторная выборка!Проблема в том что если я выбираю из списка в 1 блоке , то значения передаються и всем следующим!Как исправить?

```js
$('.iteaminfo select').on('click',function(){
       var iteamval = $(this).val();
       if(iteamval==1){
          var iteaminf = $('#itm_info_1').text();
           $('.p_info').text(iteaminf);
           var iteamcost = $('#itm_cost_1').text();
           $(".cost").text(iteamcost);
       }
       if(iteamval==2){
          var iteaminf = $('#itm_info_2').text();
           $('.p_info').text(iteaminf);
           var iteamcost = $('#itm_cost_2').text();
           $(".cost").text(iteamcost);
       }
       if(iteamval==3){
          var iteaminf = $('#itm_info_3').text();
           $('.p_info').text(iteaminf);
           var iteamcost = $('#itm_cost_3').text();
           $(".cost").text(iteamcost);
       }
   });
```

```css
.hide_block{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iteaminfo">
                            <h3>Двигуни</h3>
                            <select name="motor" id="motor">
   <option selected  value="1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
   <option value="2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
   <option value="3">Голий двигун </option>
   </select>
        <div class="hide_block">
            <p id="itm_info_1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</p>
            <p id="itm_info_2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</p>
            <p id="itm_info_3">Голий двигун</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_1">2000</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_2">2000</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_3">1300</p>
        </div>
                            <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
                        </div>
 <div class="iteaminfo">
                            <h3>Двигуни</h3>
                            <select name="gov" id="motor">
   <option selected  value="1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
   <option value="2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
   <option value="3">Голий двигун </option>
   </select>
        <div class="hide_block">
            <p id="itm_info_1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</p>
            <p id="itm_info_2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</p>
            <p id="itm_info_3">Голий двигун</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_1">2000</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_2">2000</p>
            <p id="itm_cost_3">1300</p>
        </div>
                            <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помощь в jQuery](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486769/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%b2-jquery)

Comment: Во первых - у вас невалидный код. Айди не могут повторятся. Он уникальный на странице. Во вторых вы берете все селекторы `$('.p_info').text(iteaminf);` делайте, например, `$(this).closest('.iteaminfo').find('.p_info');`

Comment: Как можно переписать код тогда чтобы работало?

Comment: Нужно больше восклицательных знаков, сейчас недостаточно понятно как сильно требуется ответ!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с Вашим кодом + небольшие правки, то :

```js
$('.iteaminfo select').on('click',function(){
  var iteamval = $(this).val(),
      wrap = $(this).closest('.iteaminfo'),
      info = wrap.find('.p_info'),
      cost = wrap.find('.cost');
  
  if(iteamval==1){
    var iteaminf = wrap.find('.itm_info_1').text();
    info.text(iteaminf);
    
     var iteamcost = wrap.find('.itm_cost_1').text();
     cost.text(iteamcost);
  }
  
  if(iteamval==2){
    var iteaminf = wrap.find('.itm_info_2').text();
    info.text(iteaminf);
    
     var iteamcost = wrap.find('.itm_cost_2').text();
     cost.text(iteamcost);
  }
  
  if(iteamval==3){
    var iteaminf = wrap.find('.itm_info_3').text();
    info.text(iteaminf);
    
     var iteamcost = wrap.find('.itm_cost_3').text();
     cost.text(iteamcost);
  }
});
```

```css
.hide_block{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iteaminfo">
  <h3>Двигуни</h3>
  <select name="motor" class="motor">
    <option value="1" selected>Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
    <option value="2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
    <option value="3">Голий двигун </option>
  </select>
  <div class="hide_block">
    <p class="itm_info_1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</p>
    <p class="itm_info_2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</p>
    <p class="itm_info_3">Голий двигун</p>
    <p class="itm_cost_1">2000</p>
    <p class="itm_cost_2">2000</p>
    <p class="itm_cost_3">1300</p>
  </div>
  
  <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
  <div class="cost">цена</div>
</div>
  
<div class="iteaminfo">
    <h3>Двигуни</h3>
    <select name="gov" class="motor">
     <option selected  value="1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
     <option value="2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
     <option value="3">Голий двигун </option>
     </select>
    <div class="hide_block">
      <p class="itm_info_1">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</p>
      <p class="itm_info_2">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</p>
      <p class="itm_info_3">Голий двигун</p>
      <p class="itm_cost_1">2000</p>
      <p class="itm_cost_2">2000</p>
      <p class="itm_cost_3">1300</p>
    </div>
   <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
  <div class="cost">цена</div>
</div>
```

P.S: `id` - уникальный идентификатор, может быть только в ед. числе на странице.

Или так например:

```js
$('.iteaminfo select').on('click',function(){
  
      var 
      iteamval = $(this).children(":selected").html(),
      wrap = $(this).closest('.iteaminfo'),
      price = $(this).children(":selected").data('price'),
      info = wrap.find('.p_info'),
      cost = wrap.find('.cost');
  
      info.text(iteamval);
      cost.html(price);

});
```

```css
.hide_block{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iteaminfo">
  <h3>Двигуни</h3>
  <select name="motor" id="motor">
    <option value="1" selected data-price="2000">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="2000">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="1300">Голий двигун </option>
  </select>
  
  <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
  <p>Ціна: <div class="cost"></div></p>
</div>
  
<div class="iteaminfo">
    <h3>Двигуни</h3>
    <select name="gov" id="motor">
     <option value="1" selected  data-price="2000">Двигун Комплектний 2.2CDi 313</option>
     <option value="2" data-price="2000">Двигун Комплектний 2.9 Tdi 312</option>
     <option value="3" data-price="1300">Голий двигун </option>
     </select>
   <p class="p_info">Виберіть двигун зі списку вище!</p>
   <p>Ціна: <div class="cost"></div></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Все работает , но почемуто цена не добавляеться!

Comment: Ошибка у меня, где вы так выучили jquery???

Comment: @GenralSite,  просто у Вас в коде не нашла где `.cost` стоит, добавила свой. Может быть у Вас в другом месте цена выводится и из-за этого ошибка. Да я можно сказать особо и не знаю jquery )

Answer (score 0):

Думаю как то так:

```
$('.iteaminfo select').click(function() {
   var self = $(this),
   pInfo = $('.p_info', self.parent()),
   //pCost = $(".cost"),
   val = self.val(),
   info = $('#itm_info_' + val),
   cost = $('#itm_cost_' + val);
   pInfo.text(info);
   //pCost.text(cost);
   return false;
});
```

А вообще не понимаю зачем вам столько классов и идов. ненадо так делать, когда у вас есть конкретные теги и их содержимое.